# Error in Compiled function at runtime in spatial competition model

Tags: compile, convolution

I just did a model of spatial competition between two species with different competitive ability & dispersal rates on a lattice with variables nrs of individuals per site. To speed it up I tried to use Compile - but I get an error at runtime. It works OK though if I run it uncompiled. Anybody any ideas what I might be doing wrong? My code is

```
gridsize = 30;
k = 1000;
zeroMatrix[n_, m_] := Table[0, {n}, {m}];
initSpace[n_, m_, k_] := Block[{s},
   s = { zeroMatrix[n, m], zeroMatrix[n, m] };
   s[[1, 1, 1]] = k;
   s[[2, n, m]] = k;
   Return[s];
   ];
current = initSpace[gridsize, gridsize, k];
```

This function does one time step iteration, using synchronous updating:

```
stepC = Compile[{{current, _Real, 3}, {b, _Real, 1}, {disp, _Real, 
     1}, {fitness, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{tmp, k, k2, n, m, curr = current},
    n = Dimensions[curr][[2]];
    m = Dimensions[curr][[3]];
    Do[
     curr[[species]] *= b[[species]];
     curr[[species]] += 
      Map[Round, 
       GaussianFilter[curr[[species]], disp[[species]]], {2}];
     , {species, 2}];
    tmp = (fitness[[1]]*curr[[1]] + fitness[[2]]*curr[[2]]);
    k = Max[curr];
    Do[
     k2 = If[tmp[[i, j]] < k, tmp[[i, j]], k];
     tmp[[i, j]] = If[ tmp[[i, j]] == 0, 1, tmp[[i, j]] ];
     curr[[1, i, j]] = k2*fitness[[1]]*curr[[1, i, j]] / tmp [[i, j]];
     curr[[2, i, j]] = k2*fitness[[2]]*curr[[2, i, j]] / tmp [[i, j]];
     , {j, m}, {i, n}];
    curr
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

I then define a function to display the densities of the two species:

```
getImage[current_] := Module[{img},
   img = Map[{#/k, 0, 0} &, current[[1]], {2} ];
   img += Map[{0, 0, #/k} &, current[[2]], {2} ];
   Return[Graphics[Raster[img]]];
   ];
```

And iterate and display an animation of the dynamics:

```
b = {2.0, 2.0};
d = {3.0, 1.0};
f = {1.0, 1.3};
current = initSpace[gridsize, gridsize, k];
ngens = 30;
steps = 5;
imgs = Table[0, {ngens}];
Timing[Do[
  imgs[[i]] = getImage[current];
  Do[current = stepC[current, b, d, f], {steps}];
  , {i, ngens}]]
Animate[
 imgs[[i]]
 , {i, 1, ngens, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

During runtime I then get an error "CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation."
Any thoughts what's wrong?

Comment: You're aware that `GaussianFilter[]` [isn't compilable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101)?

Comment: Ha sorry didn't know that! What would be the workaround then? Define that function yourself in another compiled function or something?

Comment: @TomWenseleers that would be one approach. If you go down that route, here's a bit of advice: don't even try to implement the FFT in *Mathematica*'s compilable subset. Better to use LibraryLink instead, since `LibraryFunction`s can be called efficiently from within the VM.

Comment: Do you know where the time is being taken ? Could you compute the steps of the evolution of the species  first and hold them as data, and then apply a `ListAnimate`  to the precomputed data, or does this have to be a real time animation ?

Comment: @image_doctor: no it doesn't have to be a real time animation - computing the steps of the evolution first and displaying it using ListAnimate would be fine too! But seems like it would be quite a lot of hassle then to produce a compiled version of my function, so maybe I'll leave it uncompiled after all... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some speed increase by writing your functions differently. It is almost always faster to act on whole lists in *Mathematica* than to explicitly loop over the individual elements.

A couple of notes:

- `Round` is listable and does not have to be mapped over the array.
- The definition of `tmp` is just a dot product.
- The alterations to
  `tmp` in your `If` statements can be done using `Clip` and `Unitize`,
  which are both listable.
- The update to `curr` can also be done in a
  listable fashion, removing the need to loop over `i` and `j`.

Here are alternative definitions for `stepC` and `getImage` which provide something like 5 to 10 times speed increase:

```
step2[current_, b_, d_, f_] := Module[{curr, tmp, k2},
  curr = MapThread[Times, {current, b}];
  curr += Round@MapThread[GaussianFilter, {curr, d}];
  tmp = f.curr;
  k2 = Clip[tmp, {-Infinity, Max[curr]}];
  tmp = tmp + 1 - Unitize[tmp];
  MapThread[#1 #2 k2/tmp &, {curr, f}]]

getImage2[current_] := 
 Graphics@Raster[
   Apply[{#1, 0, #2} &, Transpose[current, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]/k]
```

I'd also use `Nest` instead of a `Do` loop for the individual iterations, and `Table` to collect the results into `imgs`:

```
imgs = Table[
   getImage2[current = Nest[step2[#, b, d, f] &, current, steps]], {i, ngens}];
```

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments, compiling to "C" is useless, when you use e.g. functions like `GaussianFilter` wich cannot be compiled down and which require a call to the evaluating kernel.

Regarding your error message: Why don't you investigate in the parameters to `stepC` when the error occurs? You could do this by wrapping a `Check` around which stops when a message is thrown and the you insert debugging code at this place. You could for instance try to define a new `step` function

```
step[current_, b_, d_, f_] := Check[stepC[current, b, d, f],
   Throw[{current, b, d, f}]];
```

which you then call in your `Do` loop

```
res = Catch[Timing[Do[imgs[[i]] = getImage[current];
    Do[current = step[current, b, d, f], {steps}];, {i, ngens}]]]
```

Now `res` contains the erroneous input.